# Snap HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android, xml

I got the code below from [here](https://www.velir.com/blog/2010/11/17/android-creating-snapping-horizontal-scroll-view).

This code [snaps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SnapHelper.html) the items of HorizontalScrollView. I tried a lot to implement this customView inside my layout but I am not able to figure out to how to attach my layout to it.

This example does add the views programmatically and calls them Features.

In XML I have done `"my package name.view"` but I cannot figure out how to call `setFeatureItems` so that my Views can be attached to it.

The snapping feature can be applied on RecyclerView easily by using SnapHelper but I haven't found anything for HorizontalScrollView.

```java
public class HomeFeatureLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 5;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 300;

    private ArrayList mItems = null;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private int mActiveFeature = 0;

    public HomeFeatureLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public HomeFeatureLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public HomeFeatureLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setFeatureItems(ArrayList items){
        LinearLayout internalWrapper = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        internalWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        internalWrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        addView(internalWrapper);
        this.mItems = items;
        for(int i = 0; i< items.size();i++){
            LinearLayout featureLayout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this.getContext(),R.layout.homefeature,null);
            //...
          //Create the view for each screen in the scroll view
            //...
            internalWrapper.addView(featureLayout);
        }
        setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //If the user swipes
                if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL ){
                    int scrollX = getScrollX();
                    int featureWidth = v.getMeasuredWidth();
                    mActiveFeature = ((scrollX + (featureWidth/2))/featureWidth);
                    int scrollTo = mActiveFeature*featureWidth;
                    smoothScrollTo(scrollTo, 0);
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    }
        class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                //right to left
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    int featureWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
                    mActiveFeature = (mActiveFeature < (mItems.size() - 1))? mActiveFeature + 1:mItems.size() -1;
                    smoothScrollTo(mActiveFeature*featureWidth, 0);
                    return true;
                }
                //left to right
                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    int featureWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
                    mActiveFeature = (mActiveFeature > 0)? mActiveFeature - 1:0;
                    smoothScrollTo(mActiveFeature*featureWidth, 0);
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Fling", "There was an error processing the Fling event:" + e.getMessage());
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also add views programmatically in recycleview also why are you using horizontal scrollview?

Comment: @Zealous My Views are in HorizontalScrollView which is attached to RecylerView adapter.

Answer (score 1):

in your recycleview adapter you will have reference to *HomeFeatureLayout* there you can call

```
homeFeatureLayout.setFeatureItems(items);
```

**EDIT**

```
        public void setFeatureItems(ArrayList items){

            for(int i = 0; i< items.size();i++){

    // here you need to provide layout of individual items in your horizontal scrollview 
       LinearLayout featureLayout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this.getContext(),R.layout.anyLayout,null);
                //...
              //display information here
                //...
    TextView title = (TextView)featureLayout.findviewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText("view title "+item.get(i).getTitle());
    ImageView image = (ImageView)featureLayout.findviewById(R.id.icon);
    image.setResourceId(R.drawable.icon);

internalWrapper.addView(featureLayout);
            }

        }
```

Comment: And what to do about the layout mentioned in setFeatureItems ?